# Can we create scalar valued function in SQL Server as deterministic and precise?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we create a function in SQL Server to be deterministic and precise without CLR?

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_max_smalldatetime ()
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
    BEGIN
        RETURN CAST('2079-06-06' AS SMALLDATETIME)
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know SQL Server determines itself whether your function is deterministic and/or precise. Try running the following queries and see what you get:

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufn_max_smalldatetime'), 'IsDeterministic')

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTYEX(OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufn_max_smalldatetime'), 'IsPrecise')
```

Comment: I checked this. It shows IsDeterministic to be 0 this is why I want to create it deterministic

Comment: Please try `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2079-06-09' ,112)` instead of `CAST` and see if it helps (112 is just a sample here).

Comment: @ShantanuGupta: The `112` format specifier [does make the function deterministic](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61c4b/2), but you must use the `yyyymmdd` format, [or you'll get a data conversion error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d5fe/2).

Comment: Is there a way to make this function deterministic. I don't want to go for CLR function for just a simple function?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta, did you try using CONVERT with format specifier instead of CAST? This should make your function deterministic.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, I just tried it and it created the function as Deterministic. Thank you for help. I checked another case which added some curiosity into me. Posting it a seperate question.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026444/strange-behavious-why-function-created-is-deterministic-in-one-case-while-non

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: Function created is deterministic but when called throws an error `Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
`

Comment: Fixed the issue by making small changes `CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2079-06-06' ,111)`