# Creating scalar function in SQL Server- deterministic vs non deterministic -Required for Indexed View

Tags: sql-server

Referring to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021870/can-we-create-scalar-valued-function-in-sql-server-as-deterministic-and-precise)

Why is this function I created non deterministic in this case?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_max_smalldatetime] ()
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
    BEGIN
        RETURN '2079-06-09'
    END
```

Why is this function deterministic in this case?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[ufn_max_smalldatetime]()
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2079-06-09' ,112)
END
```

Comment: Try calling the first function with SET DATEFORMAT YDM or SET LANGUAGE FRENCH.

Comment: Your second function gets created fine, but when executed, the following error is returned: `Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.: SELECT dbo.[ufn_max_smalldatetime]()`. You should format dates as `yyyymmdd` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd` when trying to convert them using the `112` format specifier.